# What happens to a bg process after a shell is exited?

Tags: process

What happens to a `&`ed process after the parent shell is exited?

```bsh
some-daemon &
killall "$SHELL"
```

is the daemon killed? what signal is sent to kill it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process in the background (`some-daemon` in your case) continues to execute but its parent process ID (PPID) is changed to `init`, the process with PID 1.  You can `kill` it by sending it a signal as you can find its PID through `ps`.

Comment: I've seen cases when killing the shell kills its children as well, so running `disown` might be required to save them.